# Histonic cancer: Ok English? Or, Japanese English?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, science, medical

> Histonic cancer

Would this term be understood by English-speaking medical professionals?

Google shows only 53 hits, and all are from Japanese or Chinese sites.

If it is not natural English, perhaps someone could recommend a more natural term.

Translated literally from Japanese, it would be something like "tissue-type cancer" or "organ-type cancer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are referring to ***histological*** types of cancer. See: http://www.crs-src.ca/page.aspx?pid=1765